# Error when using a custom dataset with fastai

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dataset, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I am getting an error when trying to use my custom fastai dataset

The error:

```
Exception: Can't infer the type of your targets. 
It's either because your data source is empty or because your labeling function raised an error.
```

The code:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
class URL:
  MURDERHORNETS = f"https://superdata.quinniboi10.repl.co/MurderHornetImages"
path = untar_data(URL.MURDERHORNETS)
'''
path = untar_data(URLs.PETS)
files = get_image_files(path)

import PIL
img = PIL.Image.open(files[0])
img
'''

fnames = get_image_files(path)
fnames[:5]

np.random.seed (2)
pat = r'/([^/]+)_\d+\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$'

data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train=path, test=None, valid_pct=0.2, 
ds_tfms=get_transforms(), 
size=160)
data.normalize (imagenet_stats)

data.show_batch(rows=3, figsize=(7,6))

print (data.classes)
len (data.classes),data.c

learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=error_rate)

learn.fit_one_cycle(5)

learn.save ('stage-1')
```

The dataset [is here, don't comment on the name, I don't know why that is what I chose :/](https://superdata.quinniboi10.repl.co/MurderHornetImages.tgz)

Get the zip file of the dataset [here](https://superdata.quinniboi10.repl.co/MurderHornetImages.zip)